# CakePHP many to many relation with extra field

Tags: many-to-many, cakephp-2.0

I have a problem with my Many to Many relation:

I have two tables related with many to many relation

- Table1 (id, t1_field1, t1_field2, ...);
- Table2 (id, t2_field2, t2_field2, ...);

and the association table

- Table1_Table2(table1_id, table2_id, **extra_field**);

My problem is how to add these extra fields. I don't know how to configure the model of the two entities.

Please, can someone help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your relations. As stated in [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#what-to-do-when-habtm-becomes-complicated), the relations transform to

```
Table1 hasMany Table1_Table2
Table1_Table2 belongsTo Table1, Table2
Table2 hasMany Table1_Table2
```

Then you need to create a model Table1_Table2 in your model folder and treat it like any other belogsTo-hasMany association, but you can add more fields (and validation if you want).

Comment: Sorry, I have implemented it today. I wouldn't mark it as accepted until I see that it works :)